# StackOverflowError after migration to Spark 3.3 (Scala) in function with Window

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am in a migration of code from Apache Spark 2.4 to Spark 3.3 (in Azure Synapse).

Running the same code, in 2.4 works but in 3.3. **I am running in a bigger Apache Spark pool (cluster) for Spark 3.3.**
The code I am running is the next one (there are more withColumns, but just to summarize):

```
def windowTrans= Window.partitionBy("COD_X", "COD_Y", "date").
    orderBy($"COD_X",$"COD_Y",$"date")

def windowTransMinMax= Window.partitionBy("COD_X", "COD_Y", "date")
  
  
def dataframeAvg(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._


    val dfAvg = df.
    withColumn("row", row_number.over(windowTrans)).
    withColumn("LONG_HIST", count("row") over windowTrans).

    withColumn("AVG_COL1", avg("col1") over windowTrans).
    withColumn("AVG2", avg("col2") over windowTrans).
    withColumn("AVG3", avg("col3") over windowTrans).
    withColumn("AVG6", avg("col6") over windowTrans).

    ...

    withColumn("STD_COL1", stddev_samp("col1") over windowTrans).
    withColumn("STD2", stddev_samp("col2") over windowTrans).
    withColumn("STD3", stddev_samp("col3") over windowTrans).
    withColumn("STD6", stddev_samp("col6") over windowTrans).
    
    ...
    
    withColumn("MIN_COL1", min("col1") over windowTransMinMax).
    withColumn("MIN2", min("col2") over windowTransMinMax).
    withColumn("MIN3", min("col3") over windowTransMinMax).
    withColumn("MIN6", min("col6") over windowTransMinMax).
    
    ...
    where(col("row") === 1).
    select(/* List of columns */)
    
    dfAvg
}
```

The error is the next one:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$Lambda$5466/589672638.get$Lambda(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:777)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:427)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:745)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:868)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$clone(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone(AnalysisHelper.scala:295)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$clone$1(TreeNode.scala:868)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:747)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:427)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:745)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.clone(TreeNode.scala:868)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$clone(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone(AnalysisHelper.scala:295)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.clone$(AnalysisHelper.scala:294)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.clone(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$clone$1(TreeNode.scala:868)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$mapChildren$1(TreeNode.scala:747)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:427)
```

I am doing a research but I am not able to find the reason and how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your query plan is really long (with all of those `withColumn` transformations). Your stack is overflowing because of that. If you have a look at your error stack trace, you see that it's doing the same operations over and over again. Some more information about what a stack overflow error is can be found in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror).

If you really must do all of the transformations you're trying to do here, you can increase your stack size. The typical default value is 1024KB, so you can increase it to `4M` by setting `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` to `-Xss4M`. If you're using `spark-submit` to submit your application, you can do something  like this:

```
spark-submit \ 
  --master ... \  
  --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xss4M" \ 
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I agree with Koedit's answer on the why you should instead prefer to re-write those withColumns as simple selects.  As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76836878/1028537)'s [evidence](https://lansalo.wordpress.com/2018/05/13/spark-how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-dataframes-and-how-not-to/) it can be very expensive.

It was expensive in 2.4 already, Spark was quick enough to not disturb you much.  3.3 just causes SOEs in addition to the slow execution.  Getting rid of the SOEs won't stop the loss of performance.